# Create SQL Server table name that includes a variable value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating a SQL Server table via a trigger, and I want the table name to be specific each time.

For the end result, I want the table name to be `tblTEMP_INA_DATA_12345`.

I could obviously, just type `tblTEMP_INA_DATA_12345`, but the `@PlanID` value will be different each time.

How could I modify the create table statement to do what I want? Is this possible?

I have searched, but I'm not sure what search terms to even use. I appreciate any and all responses even if the answer is no.

```
DECLARE @PlanID varchar(80)

SET @PlanID = 12345

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTEMP_INA_DATA_]
(
    [strQuestion] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [strAnswer] [varchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Since you can't do this directly, you can either 1. Use dynamic SQL or 2. Create the table without the suffix and then use sp_rename to rename it

Comment: Creating a table inside a trigger seems like a *really BAD idea* ....

Comment: @marc_s I don't disagree with you at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dynamic sql` to do this. Like below

```
Declare @PlanID varchar(80),@sql nvarchar(max);

Set @PlanID = 123456

set @sql= 'Create TABLE [dbo].' + QUOTENAME('tblTEMP_INA_DATA_' + @PlanID) + '
([strQuestion] [varchar](max) NULL,

[strAnswer] [varchar](max) NULL
)  ON [PRIMARY]'

exec (@sql);
```

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted. I appreciate your help immensely. Now to test any and all scenarios to see if I run into any unforeseen issues.